# AngularJS : Stubbing JQlite methods

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, directive

I'd like to unit test some logic in my directive :

```
...
link: function ($scope, $element) {
   var rightMargin = 3;
   var w = $element.find('span')[0].scrollWidth;
   if (w > 100) {
      $element.css('width', (w + rightMargin) + 'px');
   }
...
```

Because the $compile service doesn't really add elements on document, scrollWidth always returns 0.
So I don't know how to stub the returned value of $element.find call because there is no way to access $element instance in my unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the HTML of the page directly inside of body

Using innerHTML:

```
angular.element(document.body).html('<div class="my-elm" my-directive></div>');
var elm = angular.element(document.body.querySelector('.my-elm'));
$compile(elm)($rootScope);
```

Or using append:

```
var elm = angular.element('<div class="my-elm" my-directive></div>');
angular.element(document.body).append(elm);
$compile(elm)($rootScope);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a unit test, then you shouldn't be testing the external dependencies, only that you're logic is accurate.  I'd stub it out like.

```
spyOn($element,'css');
#call your code here
expect($element.css).toHaveBeenCalledWith('width','99px');
```

Comment: Spying on the method directly from the element does not seem to work. I'm getting an error from sinon saying "could not call restore of undefined".